# Can you please tell me why this ajax call is not reaching the webservice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web-services

We are trying to user ajax to make a call to a webservice - Authentication/Validate but so far, it can't find the webservice.

Each time you run the script, you get, "error", just error.

The webservice is on a different web server while the ajax script calling it is on another server.

However, they are both on port 80 and on same domain.

I have been struggling with this for 2 days.

Script is below.

Thanks alot in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
      url:"Authentication/Validate",
     data: { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: "jane.doe",Password: "jdoe" }) },
     success: function (data) {
             alert("found!");
             debugger;
             var token = JSON.parse(data);
     },
     error: function(a,b,c) {
       alert(b+"\n"+c)
     },
     dataType:"json"
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>



param=data: {"LoginName":"jane.doe","Password":"jdoe"}

Response body: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Unexpected end of data
```

Comment: Can you use the url with the ip address and give it a shot?

Comment: what's that variable debugger inside de success function for?
You forgot to put ; after the alert inside the error function.
Your ajax request may also fail if some fatal error occurs inside the webservice.
I would also try writing the whole URL.

Comment: You should probably explain how you're running two servers on the same port and domain ?

Comment: apart from 2 servers , same domain,( doesn't seem possible) first line of troubleshooting ajax is inspect the request in browser console/development tools and look for clues there. status, what is sent, response etc

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of your AJAX live viewer? See if the request is made, and what the HTTP response code is.

Comment: @adeneo, both servers are inside our firewall. I would assume, as I did, that means they are on the same domain, no?

Also, web servers, by default, run on port 80 unless otherwise specified.

SRay and Edson, When I try with the code I posted as is, I get 'Object Not found'.

When I try with the url, I get just an "error" alert.

Comment: "Same domain" means that the site is running on www.example.com and the AJAX operation is contacting www.example.com. If they are different, that's likely to be the problem - and since they are on two separate servers, it sounds like they might be.

Comment: @Kenny - Nope, a webserver generally runs on whatever IP it is assigned, on the port that is set, and the domain is routed to the server in DNS, how you're running two servers on the same domain and port is crucial, are they somehow sharded or clustered or .... The domain is the name, as halfer has mentioned above, any other domain name is considered cross-domain, even if the servers are virtualized within the same machine.

Comment: Pardon me, but how can "Authentication/Validate" be a valid URL???

Comment: @ThomasW, it isn't a valid url. It is just a file on some folder and that is the heart of the problem. They couldn't provide the folder where it resides. Perhaps, they don't know?

Edson, halfer, I am trying to run the test on firefox. Tools-developer, debugger, console and I hit the enter key and it is says function is invalid. It isn't giving me anything else.

Comment: Try opening the Network tab of developer tools, hitting refresh, inspecting the request and response, taking notice of any error messages, http response codes, error messages in the console. Take all of the error messages and any other information and update your question so we have all of the information in one place.

Comment: @ricksuggs, I can see the script after I hit network, refresh and then inspector.

I see the code as I posted here on this forum.

I don't see any response or errors. I just the see the code.

Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: When you use AJAX, you are sending a request and will always get a response from the server. You should be able to view request / response headers and the request / response bodies for the ajax requests. I don't know what browser you are using so you'll need to research (google) 'how to inspect http request and response <insert browser name>' After you learn that, go back and find out all of the information for two comments above and update your original question with the information.

Comment: @ricksuggs, I will do just that. I am using firefox, latest version.

Comment: Here is an introduction to using the Firefox Developer Tools Network Tab: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor.

Comment: @ricksuggs, et al, I have updated post above with a screenshot of what I think I am supposed to get. It shows request and response headers.

I redacted some stuff for confidentiality sake.

However, you will see 1.1 websecurity2@domain.com:80 (port 80).

I don't see any errors. That maybe because I commented out the Alert on the script.

See anything I might be missing?

Comment: @Kenny, great job on getting the request and response headers. If you want continued assistance, you are going to need to answer all questions and post all information so that I don't have to keep repeating myself. You should post the http response code, request parameters, and response body. You can find all of these through the firefox developer tools, see the response and params tab, and the 'Status Code' label.

Comment: @ricksuggs, thank you very much sir. very kind words.

I will have to complete your request when I get home. I am being rushed out here - trying to do my job - go figure.

Thanks to you and everyone else for all your help. Be back a bit later. Please don't forget me.

Comment: @ricksuggs, Sorry to have to make you repeat yourself again but I don't see status label. I do howver, have response body and param body. I also don't know what you meant by request code. did you mean the same code I posted initially? I have posted the param and response info above. Very sorry I am a little late in posting this information than I would have liked to.

The response body as you can see shows syntax error. I don't know if it is because I removed the alert code.

Comment: @Kenny You can research the questions that you have repeated on the link that I posted 5 comments above, the answers are readily available. That information may help you find a solution to the problem. As far as the response, you may have a response that is not json dataType coming from the server and your browser is trying to parse it as such. Try changing the dataType parameter to something other than json, you may want to read the jQuery.ajax documentation on the dataType parameter to decide whether to leave it out or change it to plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid file URL would start with `file://`, but a file won't answer your AJAX response in a very useful way.

You need, and they need to supply, a valid URL for the webservice. Something along the lines of `http://domain.com/somePath`.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator
- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html

Comment: they did provide a valid url as stated above. This url has the webservice but when I use the ajax to call it, I get the "error" alert box and nothing else.

It may well be what some of you have already pointed out, different domains, one for the webservice and one for the ajax calling it. That maybe the problem. However, they continue to say that's not the problem. Frustrating

Comment: If you do have a valid URL but on a different domain, you can consider running a reverse-proxy (server) within your domain which will re-send the request to the distant domain. Check first to see that cross-site scripting rules are the problem.

Comment: If you don't mind sir, how do I do a reverse proxy?

A simple example would be really helpful.

Comment: With Java & Tomcat, you'd just implement a servlet that listened for requests, execute the same request out the back to a different target URL (perhaps using `HttpURLConnection`), and streamed the response back to the client. This enables you to avoid cross-domain restrictions in the browser, by crossing domains from the server instead. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Comment: @Thomas: maybe I've missed something important here, but wouldn't a URL of "Authentication/Validate" in jQuery just be regarded as relative to the current page? So, if the user is on `http://example.com/directory/hello`, the resulting URL here would be `http://example.com/directory/Authentication/Validate`?

Comment: Dunno.. it just looked strange to me! If I implemented it in a script, I'd always use an _absolute_ path as I would see no reason to make code weak by relying on a fragile "current-path" dependency. Thanks, you might be right @halfer, or maybe the OP has an actual URL but didn't post for security reasons. I'm not clear exactly.